# How to click outside the div and hide and when i drag it outside it keep hiding (mouseup, mousedown...) Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need help.
I have this problem that i need to make the div click to show and hide, and clicking outside the div and hide too, and it is working, but when i click inside the div to the outside, its hiding, and I need to take this off.
The code that i did to make the div hide is this:

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {

  if (!chat.is(e.target) && chat.has(e.target).length === 0){
    chat.hide();
  };
  
  if
});
```

how can i click inside to outside and it dont hide the div too?
I search a lot and dont find other question like mine!

Comment: ok, you wanna show chat when click inside and hide him when click outside?

Comment: i want hide the div chat clicking outside and keep it hiding even if i click inside and move the click held down to outside

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use, you'll be do addaptations for your code of course

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let change = true;
  const menu = document.querySelectorAll('[dropdown]');
  const toggler = document.querySelectorAll('[menu]');
  menu.forEach((element) => {
    change =
      change &&
      event.target instanceof HTMLElement &&
      !element.contains(event.target);
  });
  toggler.forEach((element) => {
    change =
      change &&
      event.target instanceof HTMLElement &&
      !element.contains(event.target);
  });
  if (change) {
    chat.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```